# Regex - counting numbers in interval

Tags: numbers, spreadsheet

I wonder if it's possible to find the count of all numbers in the next example with regular expression or with some formula in google spreadsheet/javascript:

**1-6,8-12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,24-35,37-40**
The result must be: **34**

Maybe it must be something similar to: `\d+?`

These are all numbers which must be counted:
(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,37,38,39,40)
At this point, any suggestion at all will be helpful. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how you egt 34 from 1-6,8-12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,24-35,37-40?

Comment: I don't want to sum the numbers, only to get the count of them. For example: 1,3-5,7,9-11 have 8 numbers (1,3,4,5,7,9,10,11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it, is to split the string on ',' and loop trhough the items.
Then splitting on '-'
When list is bigger than 1. 
Add difference.
Pseudo code:

```
for i in string.split(',')
    l = i.split('-')
    if l.length > 1
        add l[0] -l[1]
    else
        add 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if regex could solve this, but javascript is good enough and maybe the best solution.

Comment: Getting the numbers with regex ain't that difficult. But the numbers with '-' are. I think it would be possible, but I don't think regex would be the best choice.